# Permanently redirect subdirectory to root of domain with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm trying to permantently redirect a sub directory to the root of my domain. Eg. from `mydomain.com/subdir/` to `mydomain.com` while `mydomain.com/subdir/myfile.html` should remain working. Additionally I want this rule to work on different environments like `mydomain.dev` or `mydomain.test` without having to explicitly mention the domain. The below rule unfortunately doesn't work:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^subdir/$ %{HTTP_HOST}
```

Comment: Does `/subdir/` also have a .htaccess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that in your root `.htaccess` :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^subdir/?$ / [R=301,L]
```